# Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104 - Print Preview issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

**Issue:** Border and background-colors not working in print preview on any html tag.

**`Chrome Version: 59.0.3071.104`**

Comment: can you elaborate this with example because it's working for me in the same version

Comment: I am using inline-css on h2 tag(border:1px solid #000;), its working fine in my browser, but when i click on print button, it doesn't appear.

Comment: This also works for me in print <h2 style="border:1px solid #000;">title</h2>. May be some print settings you need to look for?

Comment: where to set print settings?

Comment: if you send more code or screenshots, i may help you

Comment: <h2 style="text-align:center;margin-top: 5px; border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:3px solid #000; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">Billing Info</h2>

Comment: Actually i am working on xsl

Comment: This works for me in print too. I tried to add background color even.  <h2 style="text-align:center;margin-top: 5px; border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:3px solid #000;background: #00F; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">Billing Info</h2>

Comment: It is making issue in xsl file. i dont know why?

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/chummer5a/chummer5a/issues/568

Comment: still not working

Comment: Improve readability and text formatting